# # in a \footcite

Tags: biblatex

I need to footcite a url that contains a hashtag and tried it the following ways without success:

```
\footcite{http://url.eu/#privacy}
```

Gives the error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@tempb.<to be read again>p ...otcite{http://url.eu/#privacy}
```

Then I tried:

```
\footcite{http://url.eu/\#privacy}
```

which compiles without an error but gives the footcite:

```
http://url.eu/\#privacy
```

Comment: You cite a _key_ not the text itself: there's no need to have `#` in the key (indeed, normally keys are something like 'EU-Privacy-site' or whatever)

Comment: BTW, I've guessed [tag:biblatex] based on `\footcite`.

Comment: Welcome, are you looking for something like `\footciteurl` to get just the url into the footnote, or do you want to have the normal citation in the footnote?

Comment: I just want the URL in the footnote, If I need to do real citation I use a bib file.

Comment: Then why `\footcite`? If you're not citing anything from your .bib file, then use `\footnote{}` and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

In case that you actually want a \footnote (and not a \footcite):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\urldef\myurl\url{http://url.eu/#privacy}
blbla\footnote{\myurl}
\end{document}
```